# Maven generated JAR file can't be deployed to Wildfly

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I am trying to build simple JAR to deploy to Wildfly, but whenever I try to deploy a lot of ClassNotFoundExceptions are thrown. 
Only dependency I have is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Build I am using for JAR is:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

On the other hand, when I build the same project as WAR with:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
    </archive>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <directory>target/classes/META-INF</directory>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
        <includes>
          <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
          <include>jboss-deployment-structure.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

everything works fine.
If I am not mistaken, this issue arises due to classloading.
What causes this difference in classloading and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Do the CNF exceptions refer to the _spring-data-elasticsearch_ dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy the jar that is generated by the shade plugin.
Once you are done with the clean install, you will get two jars. One is the regular jar with just the compiled classes of your source and the other jar (which will be created by the shade plugin) will have both your compiled classes as well as the classes from all your dependencies. This is the jar that you should deploy to your server. Since this jar will include the classes from all your dependency jars, you won't get any ClassNotFoundExceptions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, two jars are created, one with the prefix original, and the other with all the libraries. It was the one with the libaries that I tried to deploy, and which had ClassNotFoundExceptions